# What would nordic culture be like in a desert environment?

Tags: culture, geography, civilization, fantasy-races

In my fantasy world ''Diggoran'' ( pronounced Die-Ah-Ran ) there is a currently unnamed Nordic Country comprised of 6 autonomous eco-political regions. This Nordic Country was initially and still is to some extent based on Skyrim but in conjunction with Diggoran's contemporary influences and it's development, the nordic country takes it's ethnic, cultural and linguistic influences from modern-day Norway, Sweden, and Iceland. Think of this country as a parallel to a united Scandinavia.

[image]

If you can tell, this country is quite large. I estimate it's size to be over 1,052,000 mi² and it's population to be around 43.855 Million people.

Likewise, this country does not feature geography inherently reminiscent of Nordic nations. This is because the continent of Diggoran originally began as a Minecraft map. As the world outgrew the game, Diggoran became more complex and realistic and many of the current regions are based on the original biomes which lack proper consistency.

One of the unnamed Nordic regions is geographically unorthodox as it takes inspiration from Xinjiang, Central Chile, Western Syria and Western Kazakhstan.

I am wondering how Nordic peoples would live and develop in such a region considering that the Nordic countries are usually cold, rocky and mostly surrounded by sea.

Here is a rough map of the region for better clarity:

[image]

As you can see, this region is wedged in between 4 larger regions but does have access to a large inland sea and the ocean. To the east lies a land area largely based on Southern Russia, to the north is a Siberia like region which is kinda sensible considering that in the real world, Siberia is north of Xinjiang. To the south, we have a steppe based on Lothal from Star Wars. The steppe is also part of the Nordic nation.

The desert region of this unnamed providence is centralized and lacks any borders to the sea or nearby waterways and is based on the Taklamakan Desert. This regions southern and western areas are based on western Kazakhstan while the eastern coastal regions are based on Central Chile. Its capital city is vaguely based on Rancagua and is a port city.

The northernmost regions of this providence are more forested as they transition into the siberia like north.

Comment: They certainly wouldn't be Nordic (because that refers to a geographic location), and they'd have a hard time adapting. Honestly, take a look at desert tribes (I'd recommend Bedouin) and model them after that. Or just handwave it.

Comment: I guess, for starters, it would clarify things if you would specify what characteristics makes this civilization "nordic"?

Comment: I'd skip the Bedouin and have a look at the [Berbers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1199377/). Blonde haired, blue eyed people in a hot desert. Of course, that doesn't make them "nordic" in any sense other than the most trivial.

Comment: Well, the main question is what is a *"nordic culture"* in your opinion, if not the culture of people who live in the north. Otherwise, for populations who migrated southwards you have several well-known historical examples. The Dutch settled in South Africa and became Afrikaners (= Boers). The Vandals settled in Iberia and North Africa. Some Gauls trekked to Anatolia (= Galatians). Some for-real honest (descendants of) Norsemen (= Normans) took over Sicily and southern Italy. Some (descendants of) Mongols (= Moghuls) took over India. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the main hallmarks of Nordic culture, seafaring fishers and raiders, are anathema to a dry, landlocked region like Xinjiang. Most of the things that go into a culture, food, clothing, even social structure, are based on the environment, and while some of these things can carry over, the environment you're suggesting is just so vastly different that, to adapt, your Norse inspired culture would bear very little similarity to their forebears.

Central Chile is a better example, because it's a coastal desert, so your Norse culture could start a few ports that rely on fishing for sustenance. There'd be no timber for shipbuilding, so they'd have to have some pretty good reason to settle there, some valuable trading resource in order to justify the inhospitable climate. Maybe a new subculture forms of people who trek into the desert to gain this valuable resource and trade it with the old-style Norse from the homeland. These new Norse retain a few old cultural trappings like a love of mead (though its always imported) and stories about a thunder god (his thunderstorms are like wet sandstorms!), but in all other ways they dress and act like desert nomads from our world.

Comment: It should state that this region is not all desert, just a majority of it. It's coastal and northern areas are more hospitable leaving the central-most areas of this region as a desert. It does have coastal areas so it's not landlocked like Xinjiang either.

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem: where will they find oaks to do their rituals? Norses need oaks to do sacrifices, both animal and human. The oak was the World Tree, all oaks are projections of the World Tree, not representations but projections, they are the world tree projected on Midgard. Being projections they could not simply replace it with, say, palms. That would hamper their rituals, at least until they contact other spirits and learn to do new rituals.

Answer (score 0):

The primary differences are probably going to be that a northern cultures must deal with a several-month winter, while the desert tribe has to deal with a less seasonal variation, but probably does not have the huge surplus of a summer harvest. So they will be concerned with different things and consider different behaviors to be prudent and proper.

The northern tribe is very concerned with calendars. They need to know when spring arrives and it's time to plant, when to harvest, when to be prepared for winter storms or summer rains. They also need to be prepared to live through the winter. That means stores of food and fuel. And any other material they are likely to need. Their buildings must be weather resistant. Their clothing must be suitable for cold weather. They must look after their farm animals as well, so they need all that stuff for their cattle etc.

A desert folk is less likely to be doing this sort of seasonal prep. They are more likely to have a steady, if smaller, source of all their material needs. And having a huge stock of grain etc. is not completely free of problems. It's a draw for rats and other vermin, for example. They may have a seasonal cycle, but it probably is far less extreme. They probably switch from dry-season to really-extremely-dry-season. When I visited New Mexico, they called a storm that produced 1 millimeter of rain "monsoon season."

Winter for a northern tribe also means they tend to be shut-ins. They must have cultural methods to allow people to be crammed in together for months and not go berserk. They need a lot of amusements and festivals and entertainments. These need to use up the energy of the fighting-aged men so they don't get to pounding on each other from boredom. Otherwise, some accidental insult festers, and after a few weeks the knives come out. So they will have festivals and feasting, songs and dances, poetry and plays. And all sorts of arts-and-crafts, possibly heavily oriented to looking after their tasks for the warm part of the year. Repairing equipment and such. Exercising to stay in shape for the work they will need to do in the spring.

The desert tribe will do such things much less seasonally. They will tend to have a more constant level of effort for all the tasks they need to do. And when your neighbor gets on your nerves you can go and cool off by following the herds for a few days. They will have a lot of activities that are suitable for very small groups, from one person up to the largest herds, say five or six people.

The northern tribe probably has some kind of calendar because dates are very important. Maybe they have something like Stonehenge. The desert tribe is more interested in directions. So they will be aware of patterns in the stars for the purpose of navigation in the un-tracked desert. Though maybe there are desert storms at one time of year.

The northern tribe will have cultural festivals and celebrations marking the parts of the year. Longest day, shortest day, first day of spring, harvest festival, etc. They will have big feasts on these days. Sometimes to use up the stored food because the new harvest is about to come in. Sometimes because the new harvest has been stored up and they have more than they need for winter. The cycle of the seasons will mean they must fill up when there is plenty.

The desert dwellers will put a premium on moderation. Having a big festival will tend to be counter-indicated because they won't do so much storing up. They have a constant level of production, or at least less of a seasonal variation.

Answer (score 0):

**Adventure, travel and adaptation.**

- They'd (for some unspecified reason be forced to leave their homelands) and learn along the way.
- They'd encounter Slavic languages (from whence they'd maybe get their name of "You mountain dweller" or Diggoran or "you farmer", depending on etymology. Maybe coincidence is involved in the naming.).
- They would learn to cope with every environment they encountered as they went along, learning to follow the herds to watering holes (not so different from following dear in the north), testing the edibility of plants, (a little at a time) as in the north, foraging for roots, and trapping small critters. Communicating/trading with the peoples/tribes encountered along the way.
- Water storage would be animal skins. No change there, no-one eats snow, dangerous.
- Protection from the heat, cloth from fibrous plants and leather. Not so many layers or firs needed as in the North-except at night.
- For water, follow the wildlife - they have the smell, instincts and the memory.
- Dwellings, shelter - skins and fabric, some local wood/bamboo - essentially whatever the locals use.
- Tools, mankind has always made use of the local stone, meteorites, mineral deposits - little changes. Basic tools can be made of wood/flint/plant-fibers and resin. Failing that bone/local-stone and sinew glued with animal gluten.

Since the Germanic tribes had had contact with the Romans prior to migration to the North (North-East in the case of "Nordic tribes") they would certainly have encountered pottery (and cement), plumbing, viaducts and perhaps most importantly aqueducts. They would know enough about irrigation to grow crops with a plentiful supply of water from the lake illustrated, but they would need to defend the path from the lake to the new homeland to ensure continuance of supply. This could only occur upon settling, as could brick (pottery + cement) houses.

As to animal husbandry, goats make good substitutes for reindeer, failing that horses brought from the Siberian tundra can be kept alive and used for work and meat/milk/cheese/[beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis) as they were there.

**TLDR.**

It would take time for them to get there, they'd encounter the locals along the way, they'd adapt their tech to fit the available materials. Water is the key to survival, they've learned to harness it.

Comment: I've used the word ''Diggoran'' for this world for a very long time and it's origins to my knowledge are murky. Does it actually mean ''you mountain dweller'' in some language?

Comment: @Hiccaries Added water supply and justification.